Honoring Your Lover by Eating Him
Looking for a short story in a Fantasy/SF anthology. I read it in Vietnam in middle 1971, so the anthology was probably 1969/1970.
The story has 12 sections, each representing a consecutive day. In each the reader is told how to prepare and consume part of your lover, with it being made pretty clear that the reader is expected to be a woman. In each chapter the writer ruminates on the nature of love, and the consumption is presented as an act of love with religious overtones, starting with the number 12.

This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy as defined in the [FAQ]

@Valorum - It was part of a Fantasy/SF anthology. The early 70s, in particular, were a period of enormous experimentation, and this was a pretty extreme case. But the other stories did not leave the impression on me that this one did. If this is not SF, would Matteson's "Born of Man and Woman" qualify?

Science fiction and fantasy are not defined in the FAQ. There have been many definitions of science fiction and your idiosyncratic definition (whatever it might be) does not have the force of law.

@user14111 Very much agree with your comment. Also: I really hope this gets identified! It's ringing vague bells, and I wanna read it! :)

There was a Larry Niven essay on how to write science fiction (that I can't lay my hands on at the moment!) where he mentions not being afraid to use wacky ideas, "preparing your lover as a cannibal banquet" is one of the examples that has stuck in my mind.  So whatever the story is, Niven probably knew it and considered it SF.

@WhatRoughBeast - You should edit that into your question so that we know it's on-topic. As things stand your question could be about a mundane plan to murder and eat someone

@Valorum We already know the question is on topic, because the question as originally posed—about a religious ritual consumption of one's lover across 12 days tied to numerological meditations—is fantastical in and of itself full stop.

@Lexible - By your estimation Silence of the Lambs is on topic because it's about a man who kills and skins other people because he hears voices in his head.

@Valorum - No, that's just your run-of-the-mill lunatic. Francis Dolarhyde was the main antagonist, and all of the book is about tracking him down.  This story made it clear that  the speaker acts from love, and is preaching to others. Given the state of feminist extremists in the early 70's, this was certainly unlikely but not actually impossible. It was an out-there exploration of a (barely) possible society. It was not that far from an acceptably SF story of a society controlled by women, where each year the wives would strive to produce the heaviest husband, with the winner eaten by all.
